# How to loop all groups AND users within those groups in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using the standard Django auth framework. How do I list all groups AND all users within those groups?

So far I am able to list all the known groups, but not the users within those groups.

For example in `views.py` I have:

```
def group_management(request):
    group_list = Group.objects.all()
    return render(request, "app/group_management.html", {"group_list": group_list})
```

In `group_management.html` I have:

```
{% if group_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for group in group_list %}
        <li>{{ group.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No group are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

How do I extend this loop to include users associated with in that group. E.g.

```
{% if group_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for group in group_list %}
        <li>{{ group.name }}. USERS:
        {% for user in group_user_list %}
        {{user.username}} ,
        {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No group are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I assume there is some extra code required in `views.py` but am unsure of where to start.

Comment: How are groups and users related? Can you show your models?

Comment: @DanielHolmes I am using the standard Django auth framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` model is linked to the `Group` model via a `ManyToMany` relationship using the [`PermissionsMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin).

Thus, you don't need to add any extra code to your view. You can use a reverse lookup directly in the template, like so:

```
{% for group in group_list %}
    <li>{{ group.name }}. USERS:
    {% for user in group.user_set.all %}
        {{user.username}} ,
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can read more on reverse lookups [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

Comment: Thanks, if I wanted to list the users for just one group by referring to the group.id how would I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `group.id` will just give the primary key of that group. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Maybe `Group.objects.get(id=grant_id).user_set.all()` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
group_list = Group.objects.all()
for group in group_list:
    group.user_list = User.objects.filter(groups=group)
```

Then you can, for example, use it in this way:

```
for group in group_list:
    print(group)
    for user in group.user_list:
        print(user)
```